# 1c Bitrix iBlock получение ссылки на загруженный файл

Tags: php, битрикс

Не могу получить ссылку на загруженный файл. В iBlock уже реализована загрузка файлов на сервер, я пытаюсь получить ссылку на загруженный файл в файле init.php. Никак не могу получить.
Кто может помочь?

событие iBlock

```
AddEventHandler('iblock','OnAfterIBlockElementAdd','my_OnAfterIBlockElementAdd');
```

Comment: опишите более подробно проблематику. Как именно вы хотите получить путь, какое событие используете - приведите пример кода

Comment: Обновил. пытался получить по этой документации https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cfile/getfilearray.php

Comment: как у вас загружаются файлы ? Как вы пытаетесь обрабатывать поля (дайте код). Вы смотрели что приходит в параметрах обработчика ?

Comment: + то что вы прислали это событие которое отлавливает добавление элемента. Есть еще событие зименения https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/events/onafteriblockelementupdate.php

Comment: полный код приведите обработчика, как-то трудно догадаться по строке вызова события что находится в обработчике

Comment: я в битриксе вообще новичок. Я делаю интеграцию с АмоСРМ. я только знаю как получить передаваемые данные в форме с событием OnAfterIBlockElementAdd. Как у них остальное происходит я не знаю. т.е просто так по id записи получить файл никак?

Comment: Так а где код получения даннных из файла? Вы привели только код вызова обработчика. Что вы написали в самом обработчике? Где код метода `my_OnAfterIBlockElementAdd`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 CFile::GetPath($arElement["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]);
```

в $arElement["PREVIEW_PICTURE"] должна быть ID файла
взято из

[Документацыя по этому методу](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cfile/getpath.php)